# Jax-RS - ContainerResponseFilter's filter only triggered sometimes

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, cross-domain, axios

I'm trying to build a web server and access it from a webapp with a different origin. Therefore, I've added a CORS filter to allow CORS requests, which looks like this:

```
@Provider
public class CORSFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    private static final List<String> allowedOrigins = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
            "http://127.0.0.1:8080",
            "127.0.0.1:8080",
            "http://localhost:8080",
            "localhost:8080"
    ));
    private static final String defaultOrigin = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void filter(final ContainerRequestContext requestContext,
                       final ContainerResponseContext cres) throws IOException {
        final String requestOrigin = requestContext.getHeaders().getFirst("Origin");
        logger.info("CORS filter triggered; origins = " + requestOrigin + ", request = "
                + requestContext.getUriInfo().getPath());
        final String acceptedOrigin = allowedOrigins.contains(requestOrigin) ? requestOrigin : defaultOrigin;
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", acceptedOrigin);
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        cres.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1209600");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `filter` only seems to be triggered sometimes, and when I say *sometimes* it is really unpredictable: it is going to work for 1 or 2 hours, then stop working only for GET requests, then only work for anonymous (no authentication required) requests, etc.

I get the following error on the browser:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:18080/users-service/rest/users/by_ids. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

A few more important points:

- I use Shiro for authentication and to secure resources accesses
- All my requests always work using Postman

Comment: Is `localhost` correctly mapped to `127.0.0.1`? The loopback set in hosts file. What if you try your local IP address, 192.168.xx.xx, in the CORS filter and change it in postman / browser? You could avoid the `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `::1` issue

Comment: Good remark. I realised that it didn't work using 127.0.0.1 so I had updated my code, but it didn't solve everything. I still get randomly denied on POST or GET requests. I'm updating my code to reflect your comment.